# Get initial vector from Gaussian rolling window vector

Tags: python, pandas, gaussian

I am using a rolling window with a gaussian window type on a time series vector.
I would like to know how to get back initial time series using the output of the rolling window function if it is possible.

e.g.:

```
winsize=2
sigma=1.1
foo=pandas.DataFrame([1,4,6,10,23,42])
bar=foo.rolling(window=winsize,win_type='gaussian',center=False).mean(std=sigma)
```

How can I get back 'foo' vector if I only have 'bar'?

Comment: Your question is not a programming question, but a signal processing question: Is the Gaussian blur reversible?

Comment: And I assume the answer is no, isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. From what I know of signal processing some FIR filters can be undone, but not all, and not always with full recovery of original values. You can try googleing for reversing gaussian FIR filters. Maybe you'll find something!